# Parsing a file of book data

Tags: c++, file, parsing

I am trying to parse a file that contains book information. The file is structured like this. "The Hunger Games, 978-1-40-710908-4, 0". This is all on one line, and then it repeats. The book name, "The Hunger Games" needs to go into one vector. The ISBN number "978-1-40-710908-4" into another vector, and lastly the last single digit number will go into another vector.

However, the file can be missing some stuff, for example one line could look like this, "Harry Potter, 978-1-40-528790-9". As you can see the last number is missing, if it is not present in the line, it should be defaulted to "0". Another line can look like this "Book", which does not have the ISBN or the last number. I am having trouble putting in info whenever there is nothing, like the two examples above. Here is my simple code so far. I am only allowed to use the libraries that are below, so no sstream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> BookName;
    vector <string> BookNum;
    vector <string> BookAvailability;
    ifstream inFS;

    inFS.open("file_name.txt");
    string line;
    while (!inFS.fail()) {
        getline(inFS, line);
        int firstComma = line.find(',');
        int secondComma = line.find(',', firstComma + 1);

        string bookName = line.substr(0, firstComma);

        string bookISBN = "000-0-00-000000-0";
        string bookAvail = "0";

        if (firstComma != string::npos) {

            if (secondComma != string::npos) {
                bookISBN = line.substr(firstComma + 2, secondComma - firstComma - 2);
            }
            if (secondComma != string::npos || line.find('-', firstComma + 1) == string::npos) {
                bookAvail = line.substr(secondComma + 2);
            }

            BookName.push_back(bookName);
            BookNum.push_back(bookISBN);
            BookAvailability.push_back(bookAvail);

        }
    }

    // This for loop is only for testing 
    for (int i = 0; i < BookName.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Name : " << BookName.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "ISBN : " << BookNum.at(i) << endl;
        cout << "Digit : " << BookAvailability.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is an example of what the file looks like.

```
Harry Potter, 978-1-40-710908-4, 0
Red Rising, 978-0-55-339079-7, 0
Where the Wild Things Are, 978-1-43-520892-6, 2
Spider Man, 978-0-06-020706-9, 1
Good Will Hunting, 978-3-89-687070-4
Star Wars: Ahsoka, 978-1-40-528790-9 
Book
Master & Apprentice, 978-0-52-561937-7, 1
The C Programming Language, 978-0-87-692596-6, 7
Oops, 978-12-40-528790-9
Snow Crash, 978-3-44-223686-2, 3
```

I was wondering how I could fix my code?

```
Name : The Hunger Games
ISBN : 978-1-40-710908-4
Digit : 0
Name : Red Rising
ISBN : 978-0-55-339079-7
Digit : 0
Name : Where the Wild Things Are
ISBN : 978-1-43-520892-6
Digit : 2
Name : Goodnight Moon
ISBN : 978-0-06-020706-9
Digit : 1
Name : The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide
ISBN : 000-0-00-000000-0
Digit : 0
Name : Star Wars: Ahsoka
ISBN : 000-0-00-000000-0
Digit : 0
Name : Master & Apprentice
ISBN : 978-0-52-561937-7
Digit : 1
Name : The C Programming Language
ISBN : 978-0-87-692596-6
Digit : 7
Name : Oops
ISBN : 000-0-00-000000-0
Digit : 0
Name : Snow Crash
ISBN : 978-3-44-223686-2
Digit : 3
Name : Snow Crash
ISBN : 978-3-44-223686-2
Digit : 3
```

I tried changing around the if statements that would change the ISBN and the book availability number, but nothing is working?

Here is what the output currently is. How could I change my code so that the values correspond to the ones on the file.

Im expecting that my code will read in all of the lines. Put the book name in the BookName vector, put the book ISBN into the bookISBN number, and the book availability into the BookAvailability vector. How could I change my code to do this?

Comment: Well, what's the problem ? Does it crash ? Where (use a debugger to know where) ?

Comment: Note: `while (!inFS.fail())` tests for failure before the program does any IO and leaves `getline(inFS, line);` to fail undetected. Use `while (getline(inFS, line))` instead to read, test that the read succeeded, and enter the loop if the test passed.

Comment: In the meantime, you most likely want to put the `push_back`'s after and outside that `if (firstComma != string::npos){...}` block, so you always push back, not only when you have a comma.

Comment: Are books with commas in their titles banned from this library?

Comment: Crom, I hope so. We want students to learn to program, not give up almost immediately.

Comment: Recommendation: Fire up the debugger that came with your tools (replace your tools if you didn't get a debugger. Don't waste your time learning to code with <expletive deleted> tools) and step through the program to see exactly where it's heading off into the weeds.

Comment: Recommendation: Instead of having three separate `vector`s and having to keep them in sync, Make a structure that aggregates the data in the three `vector`s and have a single `vector` of that structure. Keeping all of each line of data in one place usually will make the searching and sorting that's sure to shortly follow orders of magnitude easier to write.

Comment: Recommendation: Consider replacing `line.find('-', firstComma + 1)` with something more robust like a function that validate that the token is a valid ISBN. Should make what's going wrong here more obvious.

Comment: You really should create a function to parse a single line, and return the information.  Right now you have everything stuffed in `main`, making the code harder to maintain and test.  I would expect a function, maybe `YourStruct ParseData(std::string line){ }` where `YourStruct` is that struct that was mentioned by @user4581301, and that `line` is the line you get from the file (you won't even need a file -- just call the function with hard-coded string data).  This way that function can be tested easily, and the file handling is just secondary to the entire issue.

Comment: Recommendation: Isolate the mistake by making a [mre] (MRE), and if you still don't understand what went wrong and how to fix it, update the question to include the MRE. Typically you don't need more than a couple divide-and-conquer passes to reduce the noise around the mistake enough to spot to the problem and figure out the solution.

Comment: Ok guys, I am a moron, I figured out the problem.

Comment: SO Usage note: Careful deleting questions. The server counts deleted questions when computing when you can ask your next question (otherwise perpetual bad question-askers would evade limitations of their ability to waste time with bad questions by deleting them) and as far as we can tell, it never forgets. A question you ask now and then delete could result in you not being able to find and improve the question later if you do find your ability to ask questions rate-limited.

Comment: Don't worry. Almost all problems seem moronic when you finally spot them. The trick is building up tools to help spot them quickly. This is what I did to start examining the program, https://godbolt.org/z/xrrEesTT1 , before deciding you'd probably figure it out yourself before I could finish writing a good answer.

Comment: Side note: See how in my test *Good Will Hunting* printed twice? That's because of the bug in the `while (!inFS.fail())` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 3 push_back() declarations and put them outside of the if-statements.
Also change the 2 if statement

```
if (firstComma != string::npos) {
            bookNum = line.substr(firstComma + 2, secondComma - firstComma - 2);
            bookAvail = line.substr(secondComma + 2);
        }
        if (secondComma == string::npos) {
            bookAvail = "0";
        }
```

Comment: SO Usage note: To have a strong answer you need to explain what went wrong and how the proposed changes fix the problem. This makes the answer much easier to learn from for future askers who find this page.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fix. And you gave a self-answer to boot! For readers who come later, it would probably be useful to have more explanation. You could say, for example, why the `push_back` calls need to be outside the if-statement. What happens if they are not outside? Also, you might want to show the same code you had in the question, rather than just a fragment. Did you take any of the other suggestions from the comments, for example, the one about moving `getline` into the `while` statement?